# Trouble with Grid Pattern Sprite Sheet

Tags: directx, directx-11

I'm having some trouble displaying a simple grid pattern in DirectX 11. Everything loads correctly, without any errors or returning, but nothing is actually displayed.

Putting a breakpoint in the DrawGridSquare function shows that everything is being set correctly in the SpritePtr variable, but I still don't actually have anything displayed to the screen.

Therefore, I'm fairly certain my problem lies in either the Render() or LoadContent() function which I've provided below.

Here's the relevant source:

```
/***
  * Load simple shaders and other necessary components
***/
bool AStarDemo::LoadContent(){
    ID3DBlob* vsBuffer = 0;
    bool compileResult = CompileD3DShader("TextureMap.hlsl", "VS_Main", "vs_4_0", &vsBuffer);

    if(compileResult == false){
        DXTRACE_MSG("Error compiling vertex shader");
        return false;
    }

    HRESULT d3dResult;

    d3dResult = d3dDevice->CreateVertexShader(vsBuffer->GetBufferPointer(),
        vsBuffer->GetBufferSize(), 0, &returnColorVS);

    if(FAILED(d3dResult)){
        if(vsBuffer){
            vsBuffer->Release();
        }

        return false;
    }

    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC solidColorLayout[] ={
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
    };

    unsigned int totalLayoutElements = ARRAYSIZE(solidColorLayout);

    d3dResult = d3dDevice->CreateInputLayout(solidColorLayout, totalLayoutElements,
        vsBuffer->GetBufferPointer(), vsBuffer->GetBufferSize(), &inputLayout);

    vsBuffer->Release();

    if(FAILED(d3dResult)){
        return false;
    }

    ID3DBlob* psBuffer = 0;
    compileResult = CompileD3DShader("TextureMap.hlsl", "PS_Main", "ps_4_0", &psBuffer);

    if(compileResult == false){
        DXTRACE_MSG("Error loading pixel shader!");
        return false;
    }

    d3dResult = d3dDevice->CreatePixelShader(psBuffer->GetBufferPointer(),
        psBuffer->GetBufferSize(), 0, &returnColorPS);

    psBuffer->Release();

    if(FAILED(d3dResult)){
        DXTRACE_MSG( "Error creating pixel shader!" );
        return false;
    }

    //*** LOAD DDS FILE ***//
    d3dResult = D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(d3dDevice, "tiles.dds", 0, 0, &colorMap, 0);

    if(FAILED(d3dResult)){
        DXTRACE_MSG( "Error loading textures!" );
        return false;
    }

    D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC colorMapDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&colorMapDesc, sizeof(colorMapDesc));
    colorMapDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    colorMapDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    colorMapDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    colorMapDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
    colorMapDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    colorMapDesc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;

    d3dResult = d3dDevice->CreateSamplerState(&colorMapDesc, &colorMapSampler);
    if(FAILED(d3dResult)){
        DXTRACE_MSG( "Failed to create color map sampler state!" );
        return false;
    }

    ID3D11Resource* colorTex;
    colorMap->GetResource(&colorTex);

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC colorTexDesc;
    ((ID3D11Texture2D*)colorTex)->GetDesc(&colorTexDesc);
    colorTex->Release();

    float halfWidth = (float)colorTexDesc.Width / 2.0f;
    float halfHeight = (float)colorTexDesc.Height / 2.0f;


    vertices = new Vertex[6 * TOTAL_NUMBER_GRID_SQUARES];
    gridSquares = new GridSquare[TOTAL_NUMBER_GRID_SQUARES];
    //for each grid square
    for(int i = 0; i < TOTAL_NUMBER_GRID_SQUARES; i++){

        //create a grid square object
        GridSquare gs;
        gs.type = ((i%2) == 0) ? prey : hunter;

        gs.BottomRight     = Vertex( XMFLOAT3( halfWidth + (halfWidth * (i % GRID_WIDTH)), 
                                            halfHeight + (halfHeight * (i / GRID_WIDTH)), 
                                            Z_LEVEL),
                            //XMFLOAT2(1.0f + gs.position.x, 0.0f + gs.position.y));
                            XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 0.0f));
        gs.BottomCorner    = Vertex( XMFLOAT3(  halfWidth + (halfWidth * (i % GRID_WIDTH)), 
                                            -halfHeight + (halfHeight * (i / GRID_WIDTH)), 
                                            Z_LEVEL),
                            //XMFLOAT2(1.0f + gs.position.x, 1.0f + gs.position.y));
                            XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f));
        gs.BottomLeft     = Vertex( XMFLOAT3( -halfWidth + (halfWidth * (i % GRID_WIDTH)), 
                                              -halfHeight + (halfHeight * (i / GRID_WIDTH)), 
                                            Z_LEVEL),
                            //XMFLOAT2(0.0f + gs.position.x, 1.0f + gs.position.y));
                            XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 1.0f));
        gs.TopLeft = Vertex( XMFLOAT3( -halfWidth + (halfWidth * (i % GRID_WIDTH)),   
                                            -halfHeight + (halfHeight * (i / GRID_WIDTH)),         
                                            Z_LEVEL),
                            //XMFLOAT2(0.0f + gs.position.x, 1.0f + gs.position.y));
                            XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 1.0f));
        gs.TopCorner  = Vertex( XMFLOAT3( -halfWidth + (halfWidth * (i % GRID_WIDTH)),    
                                            halfHeight + (halfHeight * (i / GRID_WIDTH)), 
                                            Z_LEVEL),
                            //XMFLOAT2(0.0f + gs.position.x, 0.0f + gs.position.y));
                            XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f));
        gs.TopRight = Vertex( XMFLOAT3(  halfWidth + (halfWidth * (i % GRID_WIDTH)),   
                                            halfHeight + (halfHeight * (i / GRID_WIDTH)), 
                                            Z_LEVEL),
                            //XMFLOAT2(1.0f + gs.position.x, 0.0f + gs.position.y));
                            XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 0.0f));      

        gridSquares[i] = gs;
        vertices[6*i]     = gs.BottomRight;
        vertices[(6*i)+1] = gs.BottomCorner;
        vertices[(6*i)+2] = gs.BottomLeft;
        vertices[(6*i)+3] = gs.TopLeft;
        vertices[(6*i)+4] = gs.TopCorner;
        vertices[(6*i)+5] = gs.TopRight;
    }

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&vertexDesc, sizeof(vertexDesc));
    vertexDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    vertexDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    vertexDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vertexDesc.ByteWidth = 6 * sizeof(Vertex) * TOTAL_NUMBER_GRID_SQUARES; //num vertices * size of single vertex

    d3dResult = d3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&vertexDesc, 0, &vertexBuffer);

    if(FAILED(d3dResult)){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void AStarDemo::Render(){
    if(d3dContext == 0)
        return;

    float clearColor[4] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.25f, 1.0f};
    d3dContext->ClearRenderTargetView(backBuffTarget, clearColor);

    unsigned int stride = sizeof(Vertex);
    unsigned int offset = 0;

    d3dContext->IASetInputLayout(inputLayout);
    d3dContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);
    d3dContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    //actually set the vertex shader
    d3dContext->VSSetShader(returnColorVS, 0, 0);
    //actually set the pixel shader
    d3dContext->PSSetShader(returnColorPS, 0, 0);

    //set shader resources & sampler
    d3dContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &colorMap);
    d3dContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &colorMapSampler);

    //update grid squares
    //   A* alg steped in built-in Update()
    for(int i = 0; i < 1/*TOTAL_NUMBER_GRID_SQUARES*/; i+=6){
        //update the squares
        DrawGridSquare(i);
    }

    swapChain->Present(0, 0);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What did you do in DrawGridSquare()?

Comment: Haha I knew someone would ask; it wouldn't let me post more code. Anyways, it uses a Vertex (custom struct) pointer to reach the first 6 vertices in the buffer, edits their vertex's locations & their texel locations. I can post the source in a bit

Comment: I assume you also make a draw call in DrawGridSquare...

Comment: You could use pastebin to add some code. Your shader would be interesting. Did you ensure that you're performing no alphablending? Did you disable Z-Buffering? (Only the first two things I ever check if nothing is drawn ;) )

Comment: @gareththegeek yep, right after I unmapped like this:
    d3dContext->Unmap(vertexBuffer, 0);
    d3dContext->Draw(6, offset);

I know my alpha blending is working alright, but I did forget to disable my Z-Buffer. That shouldn't mess anything up though, just skew things if they're off, right?